# Store the date/time in to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, object, sqlite, nsdate

In my app i need to save the time in sqlite Database.

- for insert i wrote the code like this:

  time = [NSDate date:sqlite3_column_double(selectAllStmt, 1)];
- it shows a warning "**class method date not found**"
- if I use that it doesn't show a warning:

time = [NSDate dateWithtimeintervelsincenow:sqlite3_column_double(selectAllStmt, 1)];

But i **Don't need** to store the time interval, i need to store the date only. What should I do?

Comment: [NSDate dateWithString:] maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your SQLite DB column from datetime to Varchar and pass the date as string in the query like -

```
NSString *strDate = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",curDate] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: it is NSSTRING but the column in data base having DATETIME datatype

Comment: Can you change the column datatype to VARchar? Is it ok?

Comment: No it must be DATE TIME..
Me to think like this but my boss wont accept.

Comment: Alternatively you can use same method to get date only while fetching records from DB.